# pandas timestamp series to string?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, vector

I am new to python (coming from R), and I am trying to understand how I can convert a timestamp series in a pandas dataframe (in my case this is called `df['timestamp']`) into what I would call a string vector in R.  is this possible?  How would this be done?

I tried `df['timestamp'].apply('str')`, but this seems to simply put the entire column `df['timestamp']` into one long string.  I'm looking to convert each element into a string and preserve the structure, so that it's still a vector (or maybe this a called an array?)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S))`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(timestamp=pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-01'])))

df

   timestamp
0 2000-01-01
```

Use the datetime accessor `dt` to access the [**`strftime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) method.  You can pass a format string to `strftime` and it will return a formatted string.  When used with the `dt` accessor you will get a series of strings.

```
df.timestamp.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

0    2000-01-01
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

Visit [**`strftime.org`**](http://strftime.org/) for a handy set of format strings.

Comment: `dt` is the `datetime` accessor.  Whenever your column values are Timestamps or Timedeltas, Pandas makes the `dt` accessor available.  From that accessor, you can use many other datetime specific methods.  In this case, I used `strftime`.

Comment: No, I didn't import the `datetime` module.

Comment: Are all directives listed on http://strftime.org supported by `pandas.Timestamp.strftime`?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'timestamp'`

Comment: timestamp is a column name in the example I gave. Use the name for your column instead

Answer (score 14):

Use `astype`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['Jul 31, 2009', '2010-01-10', None])) 
>>> df.astype(str)
0    2009-07-31
1    2010-01-10
2           NaT
dtype: object
```

returns an array of strings

Answer (score 6):

Following on from VinceP's answer, to convert a datetime Series in-place do the following:

`df['Column_name']=df['Column_name'].astype(str)`